# Preventing hardcode path in RPM SPEC file

Tags: redhat, rpmbuild

I am creating rpm for [apc](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc). While writing spec file, I realized that some commands may have path which can keep on changing which are required during the compilation time. For eg. these commands are required to be executed during the building time.

```
$ /usr/local/php/bin/phpize
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config
```

But the complete path of `phpize` and `php-config` file may change. So how can i prevent this dependencies so that i should not hard-code these path in my spec file.

Answer (score 1):

Because these commands are used at building time, the ideal solution to this problem is here:

1. Find packages on distribution which provide these commands or paths e.g php-config is provided by php-devel package on Fedora operating system. In fedora you can find it using `yum whatprovides "*/php-config"` or if they are already installed on system then using `rpm -qf /path/to/command`.
2. Once you know the packages add them as BuildRequire tag in spec file. Step 2 will make sure that paths are always present whenever you build the package from spec file even if you use hard coded paths (which isn't ofcourse best way to do it).
3. In place of /usr/ you can use %{_prefix}, it depends entirely on macros available on distribution you are building this rpm on. Check macro files for path macros. One link which has common macro definitions is [here](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Macros).